# Azur synapse workspace deployment using powershell

Tags: azure-synapse

I would like to know if its possible to perform a synapse deployment using PowerShell programmatically.

I have seen examples where Azure devops is used for the CI/CD, and also github actions used for the CD aspect, I would like to know if anyone has successfully used powershell modules to deploy synapse workspaces.

If one has the template files that is TemplateParametersForWorkspace.json and TemplateForWorkspace.json.

This is purely deployment, the workspace already exists.  The scenario is to deploy the workspace onto other environments from one development environment.

Answer (score 0):

The steps below will help you deploy Azure Synapse using Azure PowerShell modules:

Download the **Az Module** and sign in to your Azure tenant.

INSTALL AZ MODULE

```
Install-Module -Name Az.Synapse
```

CONNECT TO AZURE

```
Connect-AzAccount
```

The command below has the following parameters:

**ResourceGroupName**

**Name**

**Location**

**Default Data Lake Storage Account**

**Default Data Lake File System**

**Admin SQL Login**

**Admin SQL Password**

This command creates an Azure Synapse Analytics:

```
./Create-AzSynapseWorkspace -ResourceGroupName "<Resource Group name>" -Name "<Name>" -Location "<Region>" -DefaultDataLakeStorageAccountName "<ADLS NAME>" -DefaultDataLakeStorageFilesystem "<CONTAINER NAME>" -AdminSqlLogin "<USER NAME>" -AdminSqlPwd "<PASSWORD>"
```

If you wish to create an Azure Synapse Analytics with tags, use:

`-DefaultTags -TagEnvironment "Test" -TagBusinessUnit "IT"`

**Reference:** [Create-AzSynapseWorkspace.ps1](https://github.com/techtalkcorner/AzSynapseAnalytics/blob/master/Scripts/PowerShell/Create-AzSynapseWorkspace.ps1)

[Create Azure Synapse Analytics Workspace with PowerShell](https://davidalzamendi.com/azure-synapse-analytics-powershell/)

You can also refer to the commands for [Az.Synapse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.synapse/?view=azps-11.3.0)